# How to extract 2nd column in html table in python?

Tags: python, html-table, extract

```
<table style="width:300px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ABC</td>
  <td>abcd</td>     
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>EFC</td>
  <td>efc</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to grab all the td's in column 2 in python.I am new to python.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://ccdsiu.byethost33.com/magento/adamo-13.html"
text = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
data = soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'madhu'})
for div in data:
    trdata = div.findAll('tr')
    tddata = div.findAll('td')
    for trr in trdata:
        print trr
```

I am trying to get data from above code .It is printing all the td elements in table.I am trying to achieve this by Xpath

Comment: Are you trying to get the importance column? You're not being clear in what you are trying to get and your example html does not really relate to the webpage...at all. Relevant example please?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use xpath like you mentioned with BeautifulSoup. However, the `lxml` module, which comes with python, can do it.

```
from lxml import etree

table = '''
<table style="width:300px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>ABC</td>
  <td>abcd</td>     
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>EFC</td>
  <td>efc</td>      
  <td>80</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.fromstring(table, parser)
results = tree.xpath('//tr/td[position()=2]')

print 'Column 2\n========'
for r in results:
    print r.text
```

Which when run prints

```
Column 2
========
Doe
abcd
efc
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to iterate over your `td` elements. Use this:

```
for div in data:
    trdata = div.findAll('tr')
    tddata = div.findAll('td')
    if len(tddata) >= 2:
        print tddata[1]
```

*Lists are indexed starting from 0. I check the `length` of the `list` to make sure that second `td` exists.*

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear really what you want since your example of html is not relevant and the description of just `second column tds` isnt really helpful. Anyway I modified Elmos answer to give you the Importance title and then the actual importance level of each thing.

```
for div in data:
    trdata = div.findAll('tr')
    tddata = div.findAll('td')
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(tddata)):
        if count % 6 == 0:
            print tddata[count + 1]
        count += 1
```

Comment: I'm sorry. My description is little bit messy.but anyway i got the results as expected.Thanks